# Getting a text value from a specific table - Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I was able to find an specific table and I need to get no the text that's into the `<b></b>` of this table. Can't figure out how.

I'm using the following to test if I'm seeing my table correct:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('table').length;
for (var i=0; i < a; i++)
{
 b = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[i];
 if (b.getAttribute("background") != null && b.getAttribute("background") == 'common/imgs/tabfade1.gif' ) { console.log(b.getAttribute("background")); }
}
result = true;
```

Any leads into how set my result as the text I need? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Image of the table.

[Table Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hX6IP.jpg)

Comment: can u create a jsfiddle with the table pls?

Comment: Would the image of it be enough?

Comment: I'm affraid not. Where's the problem of creating a fiddle?

Comment: I don't know how to. But I google it and create if helps.

Comment: What about Bartek Banachewicz's answer?

Comment: That is what you needed? 
https://jsfiddle.net/h8jdufw1/embedded/result/

Comment: So, I set it at the code the way I thought it would be correct. Not sure if it is. Returned just "" to me. So probably I made some mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in case someone else needs what I needed, here's what I've found as the solution:

```
var tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
var container = -1;

for (var i = 0; i < tables.length-1; i++) { 
  if (tables[i].background == "tabfade1.gif") {
   container = i;
  }
}

if (container > -1) { 
  result = tables[container].rows[0].cells[0].innerText.trim(); 
} else {
  result = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelectorAll("table b")
```

Should give you a list of all `<b>` elements in all of the table elements.

Then you can peform your regular operations on them.

Comment: Like that:

var a = document.getElementsByTagName('table').length;
for (var i=0; i < a; i++)
{
 b = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[i];
 if (b.getAttribute("background") != null && b.getAttribute("background") == 'common/imgs/tabfade1.gif' ) { var c = document.querySelectorAll("table b") }
}
result = c;

Comment: @RafaelVianna I have no idea what you ment by that

Comment: I meant by the  var c = document.querySelectorAll("table b") to get the result into a variable and then show it at the screen with the result = c;

Comment: @RafaelVianna I've no idea what you want to do with the result.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I need this code to give me the text content...it's part of a software that reads the return (the data in that case) to apply a rule. And I need to make this work. :)